# SQL - Postgres - TimescaleDB - Limit results by last two dates with value

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm trying to query a table (lets call ir *prices*) like this:

**prices table:**

```
    date_value    date_time_value           price 
    03/12/2020    03/12/2020 12:30:00       2     
    03/12/2020    03/12/2020 12:29:10       3       
    01/12/2020    01/12/2020 17:30:00       1     
    01/12/2020    01/12/2020 11:30:00       2     
    30/11/2020    30/11/2020 17:30:10       3    
    ...
```

I would like to query **the last two dates** that are in the table but with the restriction that the time in the *date_time_value* column is after the last time in the first date.

Like this:

```
    date_value    date_time_value           price 
    03/12/2020    03/12/2020 12:30:00       2     
    03/12/2020    03/12/2020 12:29:10       3       
    01/12/2020    01/12/2020 17:30:00       1
```

I achieved this by doing a nested query but this table has millions of rows and it is VERY slow.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Also, I'm using **Postgres** with the **TimescaleDB** extension. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: I'm pretty sure, unless you're able to take advantage of domain knowledge about the data (like, "no day has more than $X rows"), there's no way of doing this without a table scan over the date column to generate the set of extant dates, then a (possibly indexed) lookup to pull out all the records on those dates. The rest is just some filtering of the 2-days-worth-of-data to only return the largest time value from the first day. But that first scan can't be helped, AFAICT. Can you include the SQL you have that gives you the expected results, and the EXPLAIN you get for it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
WITH first as (SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY date_time_value DESC LIMIT 1)
SELECT * FROM first 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM prices WHERE date_time_value < 
(SELECT first.date_time_value::date FROM first)
ORDER BY date_time_value DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Should do the trick. But I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do here, that said, a similar approach should work.